# Creating a dropdown menu for Plotly

Tags: python, graph, drop-down-menu, plotly

I have a table that looks like below:

| date | type | value_1 | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1 | A | 1 | 10 |
| 1/2 | A | 5 | 3 |
| 1/3 | A | 6 | 12 |
| 1/1 | B | 4 | 7 |
| 1/2 | B | 10 | 5 |
| 1/3 | B | 6 | 15 |
| 1/1 | C | 16 | 8 |
| 1/2 | C | 8 | 11 |
| 1/3 | C | 1 | 5 |

I want to draw a interactive graph for type A,B, and C so that 'date' column lies on the x-axis and 'value_1' and 'value_2' both lie on the y-axis in one graph.

The code I've currently wrote is below; I have used Plotly to plot Type A's value_1 and value_2 to be on the same plot with date as x-axis.

```
# Change Type (A, B, and C)
type_graph = 'A'

# Plot Graph
fig = px.line(df[df['type'] == type_graph ],
              x='date', y=['value_1', 'value_2')

fig.update_layout(
    title="Value graph",
    xaxis_title="Date",
    yaxis_title="Value_1 vs Value_2",
    legend_title="Value Type",
)

fig.show()
```

I want to add dropdown menu so that I can change to view type B and C. So that instead of changing 'type_graph', I can just click the dropdown menu to select which 'type' I want to see.
In addition, I want value_1 and value_2 to be plotted on the same graph. As a result, I would only chose 'type' A, B, or C to see both value_1 and value_2 accordingly.

Comment: Types B and C are not valid as line graphs: there is only one point on the x-axis for every two values on the y-axis.

Comment: @r-beginners The table I created is just a sample of the dataframe that i am currently working on. If i had more rows for all the Types A, B, and C, will the graph that I'm trying to make still not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired button behavior is achieved by associating the display/hide of the graph with the type. So from your data, draw a graph of value_1 and a graph of value_2 and group them. Set the initial graphs to be displayed and make sure they are all displayed. Next, specify in the list whether the buttons should be shown or hidden as a function of the button. In this case, there are two graphs, so there will be two hidden. Refer to the reference [here](https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/#update-dropdown).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

for t in df['type'].unique():
    dff = df[df['type'] == t]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=dff.date,
        y=dff['value_1'],
        name='value_1',
        legendgroup=t,
        legendgrouptitle=dict(text=t),
        visible=True,
    ))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=dff.date,
        y=dff['value_2'],
        name='value_2',
        legendgroup=t,
        legendgrouptitle=dict(text=t),
        visible=True,
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="All",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, True, True, True, True, True]}]),
                dict(label="Type_A",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, True, False, False, False, False]}]),
                dict(label="Type_B",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False, False, True, True, False, False]}]),
                dict(label="Type_C",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False, False, False, False, True, True]}]),
            ]),
        )
    ])

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=True,
    height=400,
    title="Value graph",
    xaxis_title="Date",
    yaxis_title="Value_1 vs Value_2",
    #legend_title="Value Type",
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the solution. I have another question. I see that you used True and False to display the values for matching Types. What happens if I need to add, perhaps, 10 more types? I can still make it work by using the True/False methods that you suggested, which will make the syntax very long. Is there an efficient way to display which type that I want to show?

Comment: In the case of 10 pieces, writing [True]*10 for all displays is the same. For Type A, [True]*2 + [Flase]*8 or less is the same method. If this still seems tedious, create a list of lists containing the above contents and set them according to type. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hi @r-beginners. How can I update the `xaxis_title_text` (update_layout) and the `tickvals` and `ticktext` (update_xaxes) when the dropdown value changes? I trying to replicate it using the go.Bar(). Tkx

Comment: I created a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78010562/12461353) to explain it.